# Jenkins: Stop build before SCM checkout based on condition

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want jenkins to stop build before starting SCM checkout step based on a condition. Is there any way to achieve this by any plugin or tricks?

And if possible I want that step to run on Jenkins master instead of slaves.

Comment: Please elaborate: what is the current trigger for building this job and why do you want to skip it?

Comment: What is the condition that you want to check before scm chrckout/update? What is the Scm tool ?

Comment: We are using gerrit+Jenkins using gerritTrigger plugin. We don't want to run build for every commit developer push to gerrit. Instead it has to go through few validations and it should start clone only if the changes passes all validations. Sine gerrit has DB and we can run some gerrit commands to validate that we don't really need to have a git workspace.

It will reduce the usage of resources a lot. I have seen "prescmstep" plugin, but it does nothing.

Comment: I am able to achieve this using strategy mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275582/jenkins-skip-scm-on-parameter?rq=1